# Sending Local Notifications after some time in Xamarin Android

Tags: c#-4.0, xamarin.android, android-service

I am using Xamarin with Visual Studio 2015. I want to send local notifications after every x minutes, how to achieve this goal?
I built notification as

```
       // Instantiate the builder and set notification elements:
        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .SetContentTitle("Alert")
            .SetContentText("Time to go")
            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.notification_alert)
        .SetDefaults(NotificationDefaults.Sound);

        // Build the notification:
        Notification notification = builder.Build();

        // Get the notification manager:
        NotificationManager notificationManager =
        GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;

        // Publish the notification:
        const int notificationId = 0;
        notificationManager.Notify(notificationId, notification);
```

now I want to trigger this notification after every x minutes.

Any code appreciated.

Comment: I guess using a `Timer` to run this code very x minutes would be the most useful thing... See https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Threading.Timer/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NotificationCompat` cannot be set to repeat by itself, you will need an `AlarmManager` to accomplish your goal. Some sample code below for an alarm every 10 minutes:

**Setting a repeating alarm**

```
var alarmTime = Calendar.Instance; // Alarm Start Time
alarmTime.Add(Calendar.Second, 30); // Addding 30 seconds to ensure alarm is not in past

var intent = new Intent(Android.App.Application.Context, typeof(ScheduledAlarmHandler));
var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(Android.App.Application.Context, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);
var alarmManager = Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService) as AlarmManager;

var interval = 10 * 60 * 1000 ; // 10 Minutes - in Milliseconds

alarmManager.SetRepeating(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, alarmTime.TimeInMillis, interval, pendingIntent);
```

**Receiving the Alarm with a BroadCastReceiver**

```
[BroadcastReceiver]
class ScheduledAlarmHandler : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ScheduledAlarmHandler", "Starting service @" + SystemClock.ElapsedRealtime());

        // Your App code here - start an Intentservice if needed;
    }
}
```

You have already got the logic for sending the local notification, so call that method from within the `BroadCastReceiver`.  However, you have limited time to complete the operation in here (10 seconds max I believe) so if you need any background refresh activities, API calls, etc. it would be better to start an `IntentService` or `WakefulIntentService` in the OnReceive method. I also have some sample code for that if you need it.